# kriskowal/q node.js q.all and spread

Tags: javascript, node.js, q

I have a function that needs the result of three prior promises passed to it.  One is linearly dependent and the other two can run concurrently.  I want to use q.all to resolve the three promises, and then pass the results onto the fourth using .spread.  My code however does not work.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
var p1 = doWork(data);
var p2 = p1.then(doMoreWork);
var p3 = doConcurrentWork(data);

return q.all([p1,p2,p3]).spread(funcWith3params)
        .fail(function(err) {
            console.log(err):
        }
```

I can trace the code in node-inspector and see that the first 3 promises are being called.  However, the function that .spread calls is not being called.  Any clues as to why?  Also .fail isn't being hit either.

Comment: I assume you meant to place a closing `)` in there.

Answer (score 7):

Spread calls q.all internally.

Here is the code for spread from q.js:

```
Q.spread = spread;
function spread(promise, fulfilled, rejected) {
    return when(promise, function (valuesOrPromises) {
        return all(valuesOrPromises).then(function (values) {
            return fulfilled.apply(void 0, values);
        }, rejected);
    }, rejected);
}
```

Note that it expects a promise that resolves to an array or an array as the first argument.

Therefore your call should look like this:

```
var p1 = doWork(data);
var p2 = p1.then(doMoreWork);
var p3 = doConcurrentWork(data);

return q.spread([p1,p2,p3], funcWith3params, function(err) {
        console.log(err):
    });
```

However, your original call should work as well. Not sure why it does not.

Answer (score 3):

The most succinct way to express the example you’ve provided is:

```
var p1 = doWork(data);
var p2 = p1.then(doMoreWork);
var p3 = doConcurrentWork(data);

return Q.spread([p1, p2, p3], funcWith3params)
    .done();
```

However, the original is correct as written.

I suspect that the problem is that one or more of the input promises is never resolving.  Try using timeouts to isolate the problem.

```
var p1 = doWork(data).timeout(1000, 'p1 timed out');
var p2 = p1.then(doMoreWork).timeout(1000, 'p2 timed out');
var p3 = doConcurrentWork(data).timeout(1000, 'p3 timed out');

return Q.spread([p1, p2, p3], funcWith3params)
   .done();
```

Comment: I've seen the use of `.done()` without args and some example with args. Is there a difference and/or best practise?

Comment: @Sukima `done()` is used to explicitly close the promise chain, i.e you cannot expect anymore `then` handlers to trigger beyond the call to `done`.